# Expired user in mysql not working after setting default_password_lifetime variable to 0

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

Some of my MySQL users got expired after 360 days as default setting in MySQL 5.7.9 - enterprise version.

But after setting the variable `default_password_lifetime to 0` ( which states MySQL password Never expires ) wouldn't take affect and still shows user's password expired.

> Error: "Your password has expired"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take affect for the new users AND the users that are not expired yet.
But it will not take affect on the users that are already expired.